# HTML and CSS rotating 3D cube

Tags: jquery, html, css, 3d

I have created a css cube and have got it to rotate. I want to be able to rotate the cube when I press a button. Here is my code. When, I press the button, the .rotate class is not getting toggled. Where am I wrong? You can also view the code here - http://pastebin.com/xSjBnX5p

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("section").toggleClass("rotate");
    });
});
</script>
<style>
.wrap {
    perspective: 800px;
    perspective-origin: 50% 100px;
}
.cube {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.cube div {
    background: rgba(189,25,400,0.3);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(125,125,125,0.9);
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.back {
    transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(180deg);
}
.right {
    transform: rotateY(-270deg) translateX(100px);
    transform-origin: top right;
}
.left {
    transform: rotateY(270deg) translateX(-100px);
    transform-origin: center left;
}
.top {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-100px);
    transform-origin: top center;
}
.bottom {
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(100px);
    transform-origin: bottom center;
}
.front {
    transform: translateZ(100px);
}
@keyframes spin {
    from { transform: rotateY(0); }
    to { transform: rotateY(-360deg); }
}
.rotate {
    animation: spin 1s 1 linear;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="wrap">
<section class="cube">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</section>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Rotate" id="button">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. But now, when i added two buttons, both aren't working together. Only the first press, they work fine, but after that, the right button does both- rotate left and right. Also, when i rotate the cube, i do not want the back side to change to black, i want it to move to the side. Same with the word Hello on my front face. Here's my code - http://pastebin.com/qZFfTsuG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be in a separate script tag and to access the button over the id you need a # before the id in jQuery.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("section").toggleClass("rotate");
});
});
</script>
<style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script insertion is bad, you need one tag to load external javascript and another to execute code :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    $("section").toggleClass("rotate");
});
});
</script>
```